# ASP.NET Core Identity not saving cookie in browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

I have search for a solution now for hours now...so here we go.
I have 3 application:
1: API - Here we have the Authentication
2: Admin Client - Works great
2: User Client - Able to login and get Authenticated ...but on every request I get the login screen again just as I am not authenticated (I get authenticated when I login). This application dos NOT save a cookie to the browser (admin does)

The client code in Program.cs (this is .net6) are the same in Admin and User apps. Only difference is the cookie name

```
    var _authenticationSettings = _serviceProvider.GetService<IAuthenticationSettings>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                      .AddCookie(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        options => {
                            options.LoginPath = _authenticationSettings.LoginPath;
                            options.AccessDeniedPath = _authenticationSettings.AccessDeniedPath;
                            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                            {
                                // Check if JWT needs refreshment 
                                OnValidatePrincipal = RefreshTokenMonitor.ValidateAsync
                            };
                            options.Cookie.Name = "MainAppCookie";
                        }
                      );
```

I have used this method in other project and it worked just as it should....the only difference is that it was a .net5 IIS projects.....now I have .net6 running on Kestrel

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong here...

The cookie gets created:

[image]

with this value (not sure where I can find the values inside the cookie..

[image]

The cookie is valid for 30 min even when I have set the ExpireTimeSpan to 60 min

[image]

[image]

Here youy have the cookie status when I have logged in to MainApp client. Above you can see the AdminApp cookie (logged in there earlier)

[image]

And here you have the AdminApp cookie status on Login as well..

[image]

I must admit... this is really strange

Comment: This line looks odd "builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)"  , should be CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme    (it does not matter in this case)

Comment: Also, are you using HTTPS? Also, its a bit hard to answer your question with that little code. is the code from the client? and how is the user logged in?

Comment: The login and authentication works... I am able to login and get all related claims and other user specific information. I am using the same authentication in the "Admin" client where it works perfectly.. As you can see in the image I just added the "AdminCookie" to the browser when I log in to the "Admin" app..

Comment: when I log into the "Client" app (where a cookie with the name "MainAppCookie" should be created I get authenticated and am able to retrieve all related user details (cleims etc..) but the cookie does not get saved to the browser...so when I want to move to a different view I am getting redirected to ligin. 
Tha "MainAppCookie" does appear for a millisecond in the cookie list in the browser but does not get saved (dissapears again)...so the app has no access to it

Comment: What does the set-cookie statement look like in the response? Perhaps the expire is set to some short interval?

Comment: It is using the exact same Authentication code as the Admin client....the only difference is the name of the cookie

Comment: Hej! I would check how the cookie is set in the repsonse,because if it is removed from the browser, then it seems like the lifetime is very short?

Comment: I am not setting the cookie lifetime anywhere... where could I add this for testing??

Comment: I mean check what the set-cookie header says in the response when you initially set it., it often contains the life-time of the cookie.

Comment: Soory @ToreNestenius ...I am unable to find this :/ But the "AdminApp" cookie gets 30 minutes valid time

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you further :-), hard to tell without seeing the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after many hours on troubleshooting the issue I finally found the error. There was a error in  link... is was not calling a URL, is was calling a method :(

```
<a href="@_manager.LogOut()" class="menu-link px-5">@_localizer["SIGN_OUT"]</a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")" class="menu-link px-5">@_localizer["SIGN_OUT"]</a>
```